# 2-party private set intersection

Tags: private-set-intersection

Are there dedicated protocols to achieve a private set intersection where one of the set is of small constant size $c$ and the other one of size $n$?

What are the resource complexities of this kind of protocol, in terms of communication and computation?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some recent papers that explicitly study optimizing PSI for the case of unequal set sizes.

- [Private Set Intersection for Unequal Set Sizes with Mobile Applications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/670); Ágnes Kiss, Jian Liu, Thomas Schneider, N. Asokan, Benny Pinkas
- [Fast Private Set Intersection from Homomorphic Encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/299); Hao Chen, Kim Laine, Peter Rindal
- [Unbalanced Approximate Private Set Intersection](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/677); Amanda Cristina Davi Resende, Diego F. Aranha

**Update**:

- [PIR-PSI: Scaling Private Contact Discovery](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/579); Daniel Demmler, Peter Rindal, Mike Rosulek, Ni Trieu